# What is the cost of storing all of the questions on this website?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, server

I'm curious as to how much it is costing SE to store all of the questions and answers/comments on its servers. I'm a newbie at web development (and basically all of computer science), and this thought piqued my curiosity. Does anyone know a general estimate?

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/70078/266359

Comment: Also see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37048/what-would-you-estimate-are-stack-overflows-monthly-server-fees

Comment: Suppose someone says: they spend eleventy units of currency... how does this help you? Are you going to have your own  data centers  like SE does (they have three now) and  hire a team of SREs to run them? Or are you going to buy something from AWS? I suspect the latter is more likely.

Comment: I know it doesn't exactly answer your question, but [our performance page](http://stackexchange.com/performance) offers some big-picture perspective on our server needs.

Comment: @NormalHuman it wasn't something I was going to act on, it was just a moment of curioisty...geez laouise...